Next.js App Router: Cloudflare CDN image URLs with /cdn-cgi path triggering 404 Not Found error
I'm using Next.js (v14.2.14) App Router with images served through Cloudflare Images Transformation. My image URLs are in the following format:
https://{my-domain}/cdn-cgi/image/width=100/https:/{s3-bucket-name}.s3.{region}.amazonaws.com/[image-path]/image.jpg
Problem:
When trying to load these images, Next.js is treating the /cdn-cgi portion of the URL as a page route, resulting in a 404 Not Found error instead of loading the image properly.
My setup:

Next.js App Router
Images hosted on AWS S3
Using Cloudflare Images for image optimization and transformation
Application hosted on Vercel

